# Upgrading Symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle (Mar 01, 2013) after last update

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

After last update SonataAdminBundle (Mar 01, 2013) I can not update components using composer

composer.json

```
...
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",

...

        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
...
```

php composer.phar update symfony/symfony

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master.
    - Can only install one of: sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master, sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.1.x-dev.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle == 2.1.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.1.x-dev.
```

Comment: we definitely need something more than just code....

Comment: I described the problem, which can not cope. I need to solve it. What more can I say? Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the version of the `sonata-project` packages to `dev-master`. The *master* branch  is in sync with the symfony's stable release. Since Symfony2.2 is released on 1 march, you need to update these versions to not require Symfony2.2, or update your project to symfony2.2 (shouldn't be that difficult).

### Solution 1: Updating `sonata-project` versions

Change this:

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master"
```

to

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.1.x",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.1.x",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master"
```

### Solution 2: Updating Symfony2.1 to 2.2

Read [the news article](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-2-0#upgrading) on how to update your project from Symfony2.1 to 2.2. Basically, this means updating the `composer.json` according to [the changes on the main repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/compare/2.1...2.2#diff-12), running `php composer.phar update` and reading the `UPGRADE-2.2.md` file on what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.1.*",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.1.*",
"sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.*"
```

It's work for me.